# Unable to install pip with "python get-pip.py --user"

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, pip

I'm unable to install pip using `python setup.py --user`, and I think my python install is generally a bit foobared.

I want to be able to use pip without sudo on my user (`vagrant` in this case). Everything I've read indicates that the above should work, but it just refuses to.

If I use `sudo python setup.py --user` then it installs correctly, but again, the sudo shouldn't be necessary because of the installation to the user directory.

```
python setup.py --user

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    from setuptools import find_packages, setup
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3126, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3110, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3139, in    _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 572, in _build_master
    ws = cls()
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 621, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1968, in find_on_path
    for dist in factory(fullpath):
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2030, in distributions_from_metadata

    if len(os.listdir(path)) == 0:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websocket_client-0.54.0.dist-info'
```

Other bits of info...

```
python -V
Python 3.6.7

which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Also, I know that I can use a venv to achieve what I want, but the point is it should work, and doesn't, which a) bugs me to no end, and b) indicates that something is just plain wrong with my setup.

Comment: do you know if you are using a proxy to go online?

Comment: I do, and I'm not.

Comment: Which operating system are you on? in Debian and Ubuntu, you can easily install pip by running "sudo apt-get install python-pip"

Comment: @MEdwin - I'd rather not use apt, as it's nearly always outdated.

Comment: My guess from the log: you install at some time in the past the package `websocket_client` with `sudo pip`. Now pip wants to update it (where it is, even though you request `--user`), hence the `dist-info` suffix. Tentative fix:  manually `sudo remove` the package from `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/websocket_client-0.54.0.dist-info`. Rinse and repeat for similarly problematic packages. Then, give us the result of `echo $PYTHONPATH`. Then try the `python get-pip.py --user` thing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you are trying to install stuff to the system Python  using a non root user and hence do not have permissions to edit stuff in the system's site-packages. Please can you run a `whoami` and see which user you are logged in as, if you are logged in as someone other than root you should use sudo to install packages into the system's Python, e.g. `sudo pip install my_package`.

If you do not want to install packages to the system's Python site-packages directory then you probably should be operating in a virtualenv, this gives you a self contained Python env for your project and can be created as any user in their home directory.

To get virtualenv installed:

`sudo pip install virtualenv`

Then to create a new virtualenv as the user:

`virtualenv my_env`

Assume / Activate the virtualenv:

`source my_env/bin/activate`

Now you can install packages using pip as your user into your Python virtualenv:

`pip install my_package`

This gives you a fully separate Python env running as your user from the system Python installation. Hopefully this helps you, if I have misunderstood your use case please leave a comment and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: This question is about being unable to install pip, and your answer assumes a working pip already. Also, I did mention that I know I can use venv to do what I'm after, but there is another issue at play here, as `python setup.py --user` should install pip to the `/home/${USER}/.local/bin` directory.

Comment: In this case, I would probably use the ensurepip module, it is within most modern Python packages... e.g. ```python -m ensurepip```, this should give a nice sane PIP install ready for use.

Comment: `/usr/bin/python: No module named ensurepip`

Comment: I can see you are using Python 3.6, please can you let me know, did you install this from OS packages, and if so which OS are you using? for me... 

```python3.6 -m ensurepip
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Comment: It's Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic x64 LTS), upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial x64 LTS). No idea how I installed Python 3.6 originally. It isn't bundled with 16.04, and I'm not sure if it gets installed when performing the OS upgrade. So I would imagine through apt in 16.04, but I really can't say for sure.